# Mysql Event that runs every 5 minutes between 7am to 6pm

Tags: mysql, events

How to create a MYSQL event that will run every 5 minutes between 7am to 7pm

sample: MYSQL event that I have created

Is it possible to run this (between 7am to 7pm)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `daily_userupdate` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS '2020-05-01 00:44:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO 
CALL sp_userdefaultsite
```

Comment: Do you want 6 or 7?

Comment: either 6pm or 7pm -- will do

Comment: I guess you could conditionally call the sp

Comment: Check current time in event proc., and call SP if matched.